# how to convert a linux cmake into windows vs?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

i download a linux cmake project which i will use in the windows vs.what i do is that i create a new win32 project in vs and add all .h an .cpp file to the new project,and then,i config the third library dependence of Boost.but,there are some errors when i debug this project,the error details is as follows.

```
>  Generating Code...
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "struct boost::arg<1> & ibeo::placeholders::ew" (?ew@placeholders@ibeo@@3AAU?$arg@$00@boost@@A) already defined in libibeo.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "struct boost::arg<1> & ibeo::placeholders::points" (?points@placeholders@ibeo@@3AAU?$arg@$00@boost@@A) already defined in libibeo.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "struct boost::arg<1> & ibeo::placeholders::objects" (?objects@placeholders@ibeo@@3AAU?$arg@$00@boost@@A) already defined in libibeo.obj
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc110-mt-gd-1_63.lib'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Why would you need to make a new `CMakeLists.txt` if the project has already one? CMake is made for cross-compiling so your approach seems a little odd.

Comment: Oh,sorry,I didn't make it clear.I don't want to use cmake for i don't know how to use it.So,I want to convert this linux cmake into a normal vs project without using cmake.

Comment: Please learn to use CMake. It's very simple to use (a lot of auto-detection and self-configuration). VS2017 even has integrated CMake support. Which Linux project do we talk about? What did you try and why didn't it work for you?